# About Convergence Status Problem

Tags: convergence-divergence

Can I get help for this question? I have no idea.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty = \frac {(n^n)}{(n)!n^n}$$
The problem wants convergence status from me.

Comment: Why don't you cancel $n^n$ from numerator and denominator. You just have $\sum \frac{1}{n!}$

Comment: Hint: $\frac{n^n}{n^n}=1$ and $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n!}=e-1$.

Comment: Ah didn't see that. I don't have any idea, started in this week.

Comment: Oh I still can't solve, where am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your series is $\sum \frac{1}{n!}$. Let $a_n = \frac{1}{n!}$. Then $$\lim|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|=\lim \frac{n!}{(n+1)!}=\lim\frac{1}{n+1}=0<1$$

By ratio test, the given series converges.

Comment: @Götebakar You can accept the answer if it satisfies you.

Comment: Yh, sure. I will

Answer (score 1):

Hint: simplifying the fraction gives $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!} < 1 + 1/2 + 1/6 + \sum_{n = 4}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: Ty for your hint but i still can't solve it. where am i missing

Comment: Do you know the integral test for convergence?

Comment: Nope, dunno :((

Comment: Then Jack D'Aurizio's hint is probably easier.

Comment: I couldn't undertand that too idk why

Comment: What methods do you know about proving convergence?

Comment: I will try to understand your answer.